# The amount is invalid paypal_adaptive gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am receiving this error in my log console:

```
The amount is invalid
```

I am working in development env, with `http://localhost:3000/`

I have in my controller:

```
def pay
 pay_request = PaypalAdaptive::Request.new
     data = {
       "returnUrl" => user_orders_url(current_user),
       "requestEnvelope" => {"errorLanguage" => "en_US"},
       "currencyCode" => "USD",
       "receiverList" =>
               { "receiver" => [
                 {"receiver"=> [{"email"=>"email1", "amount"=>"10.00", "primary" => true}, {"email"=>"email2", "amount"=>"9.00", "primary" => false}]}
               ]},
       "cancelUrl" => user_orders_url(current_user),
       "actionType" => "PAY",
       "ipnNotificationUrl" => ipn_notification_user_orders_url(current_user)
     }
     pay_response = pay_request.pay(data)

     if pay_response.success?
         # Send user to paypal
         redirect_to pay_response.preapproval_paypal_payment_url
     else
         puts pay_response.errors.first['message']
         redirect_to root_url, alert: "Something went wrong. Please contact support."
     end
end
```

**What am I doing bad?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was fixed:

The error is in `"primary" => true` and `"primary" => false`.

**I have removed this code and now the controller does works fine.**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Can you test with

```
"amount"=>10
```

Or

```
"amount"=>"10"
```